# Редирект всех поддоменов на основной с сохранением url

Tags: apache, redirect, openserver, поддомены

Есть некий основной домен `somedomain`. Как сделать что бы все поддомены вида `sub.somedomain` использовали ту же папку, что и `somedomain`, но при этом поддомены не существуют и могут быть какими угодно. Т.е. чтобы url оставался `sub.somedomain`, но обрабатывал все запросы `somedomain`? Получается, что редирект не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Добавить в конфиг апача (виртуалхоста)

```
ServerAlias *.site.com
```